# Why is the variable == 105 and not 100?

Tags: c, loops

I don't get why sum == 105. For me it should be 100 but I can't get it to work that way. Can someone please explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int sum=0;
   int t=0;
   do{
        t++;
        sum= sum + t;
   }
   while(sum<100);

   printf("sum:%d\n", sum); //prints 105
   printf("t = %d\n", t);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: sum= 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14 = 105.  How should it be 100, no way? What exactly do you want to calculate here?

Comment: ooh. im so dumb. Thanks :D @Eray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` starts at `0` and is incremented in each iteration of the loop.
`sum` starts at `0` and is increased by the value `t` in each iteration of the loop, until it is no longer smaller than `100`. If we trace their values throughout the execution:

```
Iteration t sum
 0        0   0 
 1        1   1
 2        2   3
 3        3   6
 4        4  10
 5        5  15
 6        6  21
 7        7  28
 8        8  36
 9        9  45
10       10  55
11       11  66
12       12  78
13       13  91
14       14 105
```

As you can see, `105` is the first value that `sum` gets that is not smaller than `100`.

Answer (score 4):

In your code: sum= 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14 = 105.

Comment: Since you ask to explain, then this is probably better off a comment than an answer

Comment: I just wondered why sum==105. Next time ill try think futher lol. ty